# How to set different style between different lines using css?

Tags: html, css

There is a text, it may be one line or multiple lines, I want set any style(e.g `background-color: red`) when one line and `background-color: black` when 2 lines.(note: both for the **whole** text rather than first/second/... line)

Is there any way to implement this?(don't use javascript)

Comment: It would be easier, if you provide us some HTML, CSS that you already tried, some screenshots how it should look etc. here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is not possible using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment, this is not possible using only CSS. Suppose if you want to apply the first line of the text in different color and remaining lines in some other color then you can use the CSS3 selector `::first-line`.

```css
p::first-line { color: blue }
p{color:red}
```

```html
<p>This is a somewhat long HTML
paragraph that will be broken into several
lines. The first line will be identified
by a fictional tag sequence. The other lines
will be treated as ordinary lines in the
paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Yep, I just want to get some hack(if exist)

Answer (score 0):

```
p:first-line { background-color: red}
p{
     background-color:black
}
```